# How can I map an object with index signature?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api

I'm about to write an app in angular. It receives an answer from an api. Inside this answer is an array indexed with strings (index signature). How can I map this array into a regular array?

The api looks like this

```
{
    "Information": {
        "Created": "2019-04-25",
        "Version": "1.2"
    },
    "Files": {
        "2019-04-26": {
           'name': 'file1',
           'size': 5,
        },
        "2019-04-25": {
            'name': 'file2',
            'size': 3,
        },
    ...
        }
    }
```

And i want to map it an object that looks like this

```js
export class Model {
  'Information': {
    'Created': string,
    'Version': string,
  };
  'Files': [{ 
    'date': Date,
    'name': string,
    'size': number,
  }];
}
```

Here I would like to map the answer

```js
getdata(url): void {
      this.http.get<>(url).subscribe(data => {
        // code
        }
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested any of this, but, in summary, the for loop retrives all of the keys of the object `data.File` and the you can access this object through that key.

```
getdata(url): void {
  this.http.get<>(url).subscribe((response: any) => {
    const model: Model = new Model();
    model.Files = [];

    if (response.Information) {
      const information: any = response.Information;
      if (information.Created && information.Version) {
        model.Information = {
          'Created': information.Created,
          'Version': information.Version
        };
      }
    }

    for (const date in data) {
      if (data.File.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
        const file: any = data.File[date];
        model.Files.push({
          'date': date,
          'name': file.name,
          'size': file.size
        });
      } 
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(o.Files)
  .map(function(k ) {
    return {date: k, name: o.Files[k].name, size: o.Files[k].size}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It should probably look like this:

```js
data: Array<Data>;
    
getData() {
  this.http.get(`url`).subscribe((data) => {
     this.data = data.map(item => {
      const output = {};
      output.information = item.information;
      output.files = Object.keys(item.files).map(key => {
        return {
          date: new Date(key),
          name: item.files[key].name,
          size: item.files[key].size
        };
      });
      return output;
     });
  });
}
```